# Lambda data transfer limit

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-api-gateway-v2

For my implementation of API gateway Lambda proxy integration, lambda calls a third party API. So here the total 6MB data transfer limit is including communication with third party API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lambda payload limit of 6MB is only the limit of data you can directly include in the `payload` attribute of a Lambda invocation. What your Lambda function does with a third party API during the Lambda function's invocation, is totally unrelated to the payload limit.